# fatal could not create work tree dir

Tags: 22.04, docker

recently i installed ubuntu 22.04 in a virtual machine, i made docker run to get an image running in this case this one, https://hub.docker.com/r/zi0p4tch088/rocmydocker-automatic1111,
whenever i run the code at the top of this docker which is to run the container, it always says that "fatal could not create work tree dir" at first i though this was due to the OS being installed in a virtual machine, then i decided to install it in another drive i have i got the same error.

Then i tried with a different docker from the same person and i get the same error, the steps to get my system running were:

- Install ubuntu in an ssd
- get docker installed following this tutorial,
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04
- then trying to install the docker image or container

I also tried to work as "root" or add --privileged to the run commands, as well as changing the direction from "$HOME/workdir:/workdir" to another one and it still gave the same error, tried using a code to change permissions on "workdir", and none of this worked, i would like to know what I'm doing wrong or if this container does not work, thank you for your help in advance have a great day!

Comment: Do you need to manually create the directory ahead of time? FYI- I would not suggest running stable diffusion in a VM.

Comment: Hello, i did try to create a different directory ahead of time, as for workdir it did not work as i did not have access to the file so i just changed where it was going to be created, it did not work, i also have the OS running natively on my computer currently as i though running it in a VM would be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Could be a permissions or ownership issue. Can you maybe find out from the developer what permissions that directory should have?